# CSS Background-Color Not Including Bottom Padding

Tags: css

I have the following css rule that I am noticing IE does not seem to handle properly.  I have an anchor tag that I want the orange back-ground to extend throughout the padding specified.  The bottom padding is 18px but the background color does not cover the extra spacing. Seems only IE is doing this.  Is there a rule I can use so the organg covers the entire area of the tag?

```
.AdminLink {
    background-color:orange;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-bottom:18px;

    margin-top:8px;
    margin-bottom:18px;
    line-height:none;

    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
 }
```

[image: Image of padding highlighted using F12 tool]

Comment: Is the .AdminLink applied to the a tag or its surroundings?

Comment: i think `line-height` could help

Comment: Can you create a quick jsFiddle?

Comment: which version of ie? i have just checked, it works fine on ie9. here is the demo on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nqTPG/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bottom and top padding are not supported on inline elements (some browsers won't render it correctly). But if you add:

display:block;
float:left;

it should work, I hope it will help you. ;)